# Sonar: Replace the synchronized class "Hashtable" by an unsynchronized one such as "HashMap"

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

Im having trouble replacing hashtable for hashmap because the method im using receives a hashtable:

```
private Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {

        final Hashtable<String, Object> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<>();

        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        // This "new InitialContext()" receives a Hastable, and I can't modify that
        // because that is part of a jar
        // "javax.naming.InitialContext.InitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> environment)
        // throws NamingException"
        context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        return context;
    }
```

InitialContext method:

```
public InitialContext(Hashtable<?,?> environment)
        throws NamingException
    {
        if (environment != null) {
            environment = (Hashtable)environment.clone();
        }
        init(environment);
    }
```

What can I do to solve this codesmell??

Answer (score 6):

If you must make SonarQube happy & use `InitialContext` consider using

`Properties`

See:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

So instead of:

```
final Hashtable<String, Object> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<>();
```

Use:

```
final Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
```

Note from the JavaDocs:

> Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods
> can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly
> discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or
> values are not Strings. The setProperty method should be used instead.
> If the store or save method is called on a "compromised" Properties
> object that contains a non-String key or value, the call will fail.
> Similarly, the call to the propertyNames or list method will fail if
> it is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a
> non-String key.

This means that your orginal code example should look like:

```
    private Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {

    final Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();

    jndiProperties.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    // This "new InitialContext()" receives a Hastable, and I can't modify that
    // because that is part of a jar
    // "javax.naming.InitialContext.InitialContext(Hashtable<?, ?> environment)
    // throws NamingException"
    context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `InitialContext` actually requires a `Hashtable` (which is a bad API decision, but it was probably made way before `Map` was a thing in Java) there's really no way to avoid the `Hashtable` entirely. In this case suppressing the warning in sonar (or flagging it as either WontFix or false positive) is the appropriate reaction.

Comment: How do you "flag as WontFix" ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain: we're using SonarCube where it can be done via the web UI, I honestly don't know if that's an option with pure sonar, you might need an annotation or code comment.

Answer (score -3):

It is a surprise to see Sonar uses Hashtable in another complaint solution.

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Vulnerability/RSPEC-4433

[image: SonarSource using Hashtable here]